# How to print f-strings and other items simultaneously but each item be seperated by atleast one line/ space?

Tags: python, pandas

So as you can guess from the title, I want to print multiple items be it variables or f-strings on separate lines simultaneously i.e. without having to print each item on its own.

```
print(
    f'Revenue as stated in the General Journal is ${a}',
    f'Revenue as stated in the Transaction Table is ${b}',
    f'Revenue is overstated by ${c}',
    rt.info(),
    rtrtl.info(),
    rt.head(10),
    rtrtl.head(10)
    )
```

**The current output**

Revenue as stated in the General Journal is $2,079,839.55 Revenue as stated in the Transaction Table is $2,238,120.00 Revenue is overstated by $158,280.45

**The desired output**

Revenue as stated in the General Journal is $2,079,839.55

Revenue as stated in the Transaction Table is $2,238,120.00

Revenue is overstated by $158,280.45

Comment: Use the `sep` parameter to `print`

Answer (score 1):

If want new lines, add '\n' to end of the fstring with `sep=''` or use `sep='\n'`. Also, to format the float with commas in output need to add ',' as format modifier to the f-string component.

```
a = 2_079_839.55 
b = 2_238_120.00
c = 158_280.45

print(
    f'Revenue as stated in the General Journal is ${a:,}',
    f'Revenue as stated in the Transaction Table is ${b:,}',
    f'Revenue is overstated by ${c:,}', sep='\n\n')
```

Output:

```
Revenue as stated in the General Journal is $2,079,839.55

Revenue as stated in the Transaction Table is $2,238,120.0

Revenue is overstated by $158,280.45
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider `print()`-ing the values in a loop; without other args, they'll go to `stdout`, which is already buffered so successive `print()` calls without explicit `flush=True` won't be realistically different to one big call

```py
lines = (
    f'Revenue as stated in the General Journal is ${a}',
    f'Revenue as stated in the Transaction Table is ${b}',
    f'Revenue is overstated by ${c}',
    rt.info(),
    rtrtl.info(),
    rt.head(10),
    rtrtl.head(10)
)

for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **triple quoting** with F-strings eg::

```
print(
    f"""Revenue as stated in the General Journal is ${a}

    Revenue as stated in the Transaction Table is ${b}

    Revenue is overstated by ${c}"""
    )
```